# Is there a way (in python) to rename all the tables and columns mentioned in an SQL string?

Tags: python, sql

I would like to rename the tables and columns in multiple queries to something arbitrary (e.g. every table "money" should be renamed to "GGKF"), but problems seem to creep in as some tables and columns have the same name (e.g. "select money from money"). I've had a look at sqlparse and sqlglot, and while it is relatively easy to find all table names, renaming them seems harder. Unfortunately, workarounds (e.g. change the column names of these tables) are not possible. When it comes to column names, two columns with the same name (e.g. "money" being the same both in table "money" and "profit") are again problematic, with efforts to rename one of them resulting in renaming all of them.

I have tried various regular expressions, but there seem to be edge cases that I can't seem to catch. There has to be some solution that involves properly parsing the SQL statement.

As an example of a broken replacement, here is some python code

```py
import re

def rename_tables(sql,table_names_map ):
    for old_table_name, new_table_name in table_names_map.items():
        sql = re.sub(r'\b' + re.escape(old_table_name) + r'\b',
                              new_table_name, sql, flags=re.I)
    return sql


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sql_one = "select K.a,K.b from (select H.b from (select G.c from (select F.d from (select E.e from A, B, C, D, E), F), G), H), I, J, K order by 1,2; "
    sql_two = "select money from money"
    rename_dict_one = {'A': 'table1', 'B': 'table2', 'C': 'table3', 'D': 'table4', 'E': 'table5', 'F': 'table6', 'G': 'table7', 'H': 'table8', 'I': 'table9', 'J': 'table10', 'K': 'table11'}
    rename_dict_two = {'money':'rubber'}
    print(rename_tables(sql_one, rename_dict_one))
    print(rename_tables(sql_two, rename_dict_two))
```

This returns:

```sql
select table11.table1,table11.table2 from (select table8.table2 from (select table7.table3 from (select table6.table4 from (select table5.table5 from table1, table2, table3, table4, table5), table6), table7), table8), table9, table10, table11 order by 1,2; 
select rubber from rubber
```

However, the second sql statement should have been:

```sql
select money from rubber
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd expected SQL statement rather be `select money from rubber` ? Or perhaps by `rename_tables` you mean `rename_tables_or_columns`...

Comment: Correct, thank you! I've changed this to select money from rubber.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Python code to rename a column in MySQL:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("ALTER TABLE your_table_name RENAME COLUMN original_column_name TO new_column_name")
```

Replace “your_table_name”, “original_column_name” and “new_column_name” with the appropriate values.

I hope this helps!

Comment: No it does not help at all. I do not want to rename a column in the database, I want to rename a column in the sql statement. So for example query "select money from money" , combined with dictionary {"money": "DBGG13"} should become "select money from DBGG13".

Answer (score 0):

you can use masked values and use your script as a template.
For example, you can enclose the names of fields and tables in double curly braces {{ }} (you only need to proceed from the tasks of what data you may encounter, if such brackets are already found in the text, then choose other characters)

```py
sql_template = '''
select {{column1}}
from {{table1}}
where {{column2}} == 'name'
'''

variables = {
    'column1':'DisplayName',
    'table1':'user',
    'column2':'type'
} 
for var in variables:
    sql_template = sql_template.replace('{{'+var+'}}',variables[var])

print(sql_template)
```

result:

```sql
select DisplayName
from user
where type == 'name'
```

Comment: I cannot edit the the SQL statements to turn them into templates. They are given to me and they need to be parsed.

Comment: then you need syntactical analyzer sql query. But it is a very big job.
i did something similar to parse sql query in c# language to parse query T-SQL
https://github.com/alekseikorobov/sqlparser/tree/master/sqlparser